# php img echo from another file, google drive api

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have a file, `g.php`, which uses Google Drive API and gets image url successfully.

I have a file test_image.php file:

```
require_once ("g/g.php"); // work fine i get image url
$li_i=vi("my google drive image file","my google image file folder");
$file = fopen($li_i, "rb");
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
$bufsize = 8*1024;
while(!feof($file))
    echo fread($file, $bufsize);
fclose($file);
```

I have an html file with:

```
<img id="asa" src="test_image.php" alt="" />
```

but when I load this file I cant see the image.

Comment: Loading `test_image.php` direct gives an image?

Comment: Yes shure gives  image

Comment: When you load from HTML file what is the response for the PHP file request?

Comment: response code 200

Comment: if i remove require_once ("g/g.php"); line and edit this line replace $li_i variable direct link $file = fopen($li_i, "rb"); work fine image is shown

Comment: it feels like the echo command is printing somewhere else and not the in <img> tag

Comment: What does the response of the PHP file show?

Comment: user3783243
i not understand "What does the response of the PHP file show" what do you mean

Comment: see screen https://i.ibb.co/fXDjhcc/sdcfg.png

Comment: You should use [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile).

Comment: It's not that I can't read the file from Google, I download the file, but I can't show it using echo command

Comment: Maybe your `g/g.php` is already producing some output, making the subsequent `header` call fail? Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: error reporting is enabled, no more output  in g/g.php file